# How to convert the default constraint layout to frame layout?

Tags: android

The android studios default layout is constraint layout I want to change it to frame layout.In order to do so what must be the XML code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating your new layout file, just change the root element from the confirmation pop up to `FrameLayout`.
[image: Create new layout confirmation popup]

If the file has been created, you can also change manually to `FrameLayout` by opening the file, then go to Text tab, block `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout`, then type `FrameLayout`
[image]

If you are not satisfied and don't want to change it every time, you can create your own template by opening 
Preferences/Settings -> Editor -> File and Code Templates

Answer (score 0):

just select the constraint layout opening tag and replace it with frame layout it will even replace the closing tag for you

[image: layout]

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio go to:
`Settings` -> `File and Code Templates` -> `XML Properties File`

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Remove anything related to ConstraintLayout from the code and replace it with that code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</FrameLayout>
```